# Redo after presing often Undo not possible anymore

Tags: mesh, edit-mode

I noticed, that  when I want to go back in my work and press "Undo" many times in row, that at some point blender takes me back to the start file and I cannot use Redo anymore. That's pitty, because then I need to rework a lot. I have searched in google, but did not find anything concerning this.

Does somebody know this behaviour?

Thank you, Huxi

Comment: Hello :). Can't reproduce this issue. But to save some time you can use *File > Recover > Autosave* and set autosave for 1 minute in preferences.

Comment: Hi. I have set the Auto save, but I just wanted to know what's the behaviour. If it's a bug or a feature :D